# Corona sdk call loadRemoteImage with extra params

Tags: coronasdk, corona-director

I have a scene with a number of images loaded remotely. I call for those images on scene:show and in their listener I check if the user is still on that scene, if not, I simply remove the event.target.

My problem is that the user can enter->exit->enter the scene quick enough, so that the listener would load and show the images from the first entrance.

I would like to be able to pass an ID when I call loadRemoteImage, so that when it comes back in the listener I can check if it is still relevant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try wrapping the loadRemoteImage in a new function that overrides the callback like this

```lua
function loadRemoteImgWithData(data, url, method, listener, params, destFilename, baseDir, x, y)

    if type(data) ~= "table"  then
        error("first argument must be data table", 2)
    end

    if type(params) ~= "table" then
        y = x
        x = baseDir
        baseDir = destFilename
        destFilename = params
        params = nil
    end

    local function listenerOverride(event)
        event.data = data
        listener(event)
    end

    display.loadRemoteImage( url, method, listenerOverride, params, destFilename, baseDir, x, y )
end
```